# Generating an m X n array with 0/1 that meets certain conditions in R

Tags: arrays, r, math

I'm working on a problem that on the surface seems easy but I've been unable to find the key to solving it. I think harnessing the power of R it's probably relatively trivial.

The basic premise is this. You have 32 people at a networking event. There are 4 tables that seat 8 people at a time. At the event there are 4 rounds where people meet each other. The idea is to come up with a seating arrangement across the rounds that makes it so every person meets the max number of unique people across the rounds as possible.

So basically you have a 16 (table*round: t1r1, t1r2,...etc.)) column X 32 (number of people) row array of 0/1 (0 = not seated at the table/round, 1 = seated at the table/round). And the array has to meet the following conditions:

1. People can only have four rounds so all rowsums should be 4.
2. Each table/round combo can only fit 8 people hence all colsums should be 8
3. Each person can only be at one table once so rowsum of table columns has to be 1 (t1r1 + t1r2 +t1r3 + t1r4 = 1)
4. Each person can only be at one per round so rowsum of round columns has to be 1 (t1r1 + t2r1 + t3r1 +t4r1 = 1)

I'm sure there's mathematical solution, but I was thinking that it might be quicker to brute force it in r by generating matrices and saving those that meet these conditions. Is that the best way? I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, seems better on math.SE or similar. 28/31 is a max (7 meetings x 4 rounds) and 25 is possible, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I realized after I wrote that with the conditions above I think it's possible to generate an array that meets these conditions but where they only meet seven people through the whole event. So I'm missing an additional condition in my list. Thinking on it more.